# Tufte Class | Marginnotes on left and right side, having a different size (width)

Tags: margins, tufte, marginpar, marginnote

I am using the Tufte-book Class to create a landscape thesis document. I am struggeling with the following.

(1) First, besides the regular margin on the right, in which I place the sidenotes, sidefigures and sidetables, I would like to add a margin to the left to indicate some key words. The size of the margin on the right should however different from the size of the margin on the left, so this should be a variable.

(2) Second, I would like the background of the body of the text to be a light shade of gray, while the background of the margins remain white.

Any suggestions on code to accomplish this? The attached picture is not created using LaTeX but displays the end result. A minimal working example (which however does not have different sizes for the margins left and right) is given here:

```
\documentclass[notoc]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{
landscape,
left=4in,
top=1in,
textheight=6.5in,
textwidth=4.5in,
marginparsep=0.5in,
marginparwidth=3in
}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. 

Lorem \reversemarginpar\marginpar{This is the left margin, but it is too wide.} ipsum  dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.\par\normalmarginpar\marginpar{This is the right margin, \\but it is too narrow.} 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. 
\end{document}
```

[image: Example of what I want to become: (1) Two margins with different sizes left and right, and (2) a grey background for the main body of the text, as opposed to the margins that remain white.]

Comment: You should provide a minimum working example.

Comment: Dear Arianna, I have uploaded a minimum working example. Best regards. Valery